detecting collisions between polygons and circles
I am making an MMA game and for now i have just used circles to represent the players but i obviously will create proper animations later. These players are able to leave the fighting cage and i am trying to contain the players in the octagon shaped fighting cage
this is an image of what my game currently looks like
i cant find any sites or video explanations on how to make an octagon shaped border for the players so they cant just leave the fighting cage. I already understand how to make a regular border stopping players from exiting an x="value" or an y="value" line but i am struggling to even grasp a basic concept on how to make a border for the players that isnt rectangular.

I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking how to draw an octagon with pygame?

Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.
